# ckeditor 4.5.7 imageuploader issue

Tags: ckeditor

I have ckeditor 4.5.7 in a clients site and not touched the site for quite a while and today they emailed asking how to upload images so went to show them but first when I click on the browse server, the popup box was asking for a username and password and got past that bit and then it said about file permissions so changed it to 0777 and now it keeps saying A file permissions error has occurred. Please check the permissions on the script and the directory it is in and try again.

Can anyone help please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have sorted it by using tinymce instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you hosted it via IIS or not.

- I think giving the IIS app pool full access to the folder may work.
- In my situation I had imageuploader hosted as a virtual directory for
  my site.
- I had to create a local service account on the server (non
  domain account) with admin rights on the local box.
- Then advanced
  settings on the virtual directory in IIS and set that local service
  account I created in the Physical Path Credentials option.